# Indeterminate Progress-Bar Situation

Tags: android, progress-bar

I added a `progressbar` as indeterminate state and put in a class extends `asynctask`.
In `doInBackground` method, i added one method (say `m_one`) with `volley-library`.
In `m_one()`, i have called method `m_two();`. 
In `m_two()`, i have called `m_three();`.
Now, the problem is, `progressbar` only works till `m_one()` executes and then `progressbar` visibility goes invisible and remaining methods executes in background thread.
**How do i keep rotating `progressbar` until all the methods done receiving data using volley request?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53077512/10579918

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
        private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity.this";

        Button button_login;

        Context context;
        ProgressBar progressBar;

    //some variables for accepting the volley response data

        DBUtils dbUtils;
        Calendar calendar_2;
        public SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;
        public SimpleDateFormat timeformat;
        Date date;
        TreeSet<Integer> idSet;


        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
            button_login = findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

            context = getApplicationContext();
            progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_id_1);

            calendar_2 = Calendar.getInstance();
            dbUtils = new DBUtils(this);
            //clear the db tables on start of app
            dbUtils.ClearTables();


            date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            Log.e(TAG, "\n current time: " + date);
            dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            idSet = new TreeSet<>();

            //Login button click event  ********************
            button_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    checkNetwork();

                }
            });
        }

        private void checkNetwork() {

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();


            try {
                if (netInfo != null) {
                    NetworkInfo.State state = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().getState();
                    if (state == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "nw info: " + netInfo.getExtraInfo());
                        Log.e(TAG, "Network Connected ");
                        method1();
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Network Disconnected");
                    }
                } else if (netInfo == null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Network Not Found !");
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    //          ********************************************
    //          ********************************************
    //to get the response of requested url

        public void method1() {

            try {
                //url without api for login session
                URL loginURL = new URL(your url 1);
                HttpURLConnection urlconnect = (HttpURLConnection) loginURL.openConnection();
                ;

                //http connection for webpage permission

                //type of request get / post...
                urlconnect.setRequestMethod("POST");

                //allow the post request for user
                urlconnect.setDoOutput(true);

     /*
     Singleton_Volley is the class for volley initialize

     you can skip Singleton_Volley class..its correct
     */
                // Get a RequestQueue in required page
                RequestQueue queue = Singleton_Volley.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext()).
                        getRequestQueue();

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.(my case, url)

                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "" + loginURL.toString(),
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {

                                //accept the data from request and set in our views like list,text, etc...


                                try {
                                    /* your response data stored in variables first and then stored in sqlite you have to consider this strictly, make sure you also have array in response to wait for a while */

                                    method2();

                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    //popup an error message...(Toast)

                    }
                })
            } ;
            // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
            Singleton_Volley.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(queue.add(stringRequest));
        } catch(
        IOException e)

        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(
        JSONException e)

        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

        public void method2() {
            try {

                url_2 = new URL(your url 2);
                HttpURLConnection urlconnect = (HttpURLConnection)
                        url_2.openConnection();
                ;

                //http connection for webpage permission

                //type of request get / post...
                urlconnect.setRequestMethod("POST");

                //allow the post request for user
                urlconnect.setDoOutput(true);

                RequestQueue contactQueue = Singleton_Volley.getInstance(this).
                        getRequestQueue();

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.(in my case, url_2)
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "" + url_2.toString(),
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {

    //accept the data from request and set in our views like list,text, etc...
                                try {

                               /*
                                your response data stored in variables first and then stored in sqlite

                               you have to consider this strictly
                               make sure you also have array in response to wait for a while

                               */
                                    method3(); //method3() called here
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        //popup an error messege...(Toast)
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "" + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
            } ;
            // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
            Singleton_Volley.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(contactQueue.add(stringRequest));

        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }

    //          ********************************************
    //          ********************************************
     private void method3(){

            try{
            URL url_3=new URL(your url 3);
            HttpURLConnection urlconnect=(HttpURLConnection)url_3.openConnection();
            ;

            //http connection for webpage permission
            //type of request get / post...
            urlconnect.setRequestMethod("POST");

            //allow the post request for user
            urlconnect.setDoOutput(true);


            RequestQueue stageQueue=Singleton_Volley.getInstance(this).
            getRequestQueue();

            // Request a string response from the provided URL.(in my case, url_3)
            StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,""+url_3.toString(),
            new Response.Listener<String>(){
     @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
     @Override
     public void onResponse(String response){

            //accept the data from request and set in our views like list,text, etc...
            try{
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                /*
                                make sure you also have array in response to wait for a while
                                */
            }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            }
            },new Response.ErrorListener(){
     @Override
     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){

            //popup an error messege...(Toast)

            }
            })
            };
            // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
            Singleton_Volley.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stageQueue.add(stringRequest));

            }catch(Exception ec){
            ec.printStackTrace();
            }

            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,Page2.class));
            }

            }
            }}
```

Please manage the closing } and it should work.

Comment: I set only first method in asynctask. m2() method is called inside the first method and m3() method is called inside m2(). So you are saying that onPostExecute() method in my case goes empty?

Comment: Its too big... but i can post its sample code ... you just need to use your own url for volley request....

Comment: I just need code of the async task and other 2 methods.

Comment: Code Link added above.

Comment: I got that code and made changes to it viraj. replace your code with this one. and try it

Comment: I apply your code and found that its still rotate for first method only. Running on main thread directly does not solve this issue.

Comment: It does not run on main thread, addToRequestQueue() is a asynchronous method it gives you callback when the data from server is fetched. can you put debug points and check  if the onResponse() of all 3 methods are getting called.

Comment: All 3 methods run with success of onResponse() data. How do I keep rotating progressbar until all sub-methods done receiving data?

Comment: i can't see progressbar disappearing after method 1 call only, may be the all the methods are called quickly and the difference is not noticeable to you, if not please edit your question and put the latest code.